# Can't connect to Windows Azure Database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to connect to a windows azure database through visual studio

Here are my steps :

- I press add connection on the server explorer
- fill in the server name .database.windows.net
- Select Use SQL server Authentication
- Fill in the username and password
- Enter a database name

When I press Ok, I have to wait some time and then it gives and error 40: could not connect to sql server.

My Azure server is set to accept ip from (0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255) and so is the MicrosoftServices, can someone please help me with this? I'm really stuck, I've tried about everything I could think of :(

I was following this tutorial:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2151.windows-azure-and-sql-azure-tutorials-tutorial-2-using-sql-azure-en-us.aspx

Got stuck at step 7...

Comment: Do you have the Windows Azure SDK?

Comment: Of course :) I made an azure application and am now trying to add an sql azure database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be running SQL Server 2008 R2 (+ Service Packs) to connect via SSMS (SQL Server Mgmt Studio)

Comment: The plus Service Packs is the key, I take it you have SP1 on then. When they (MSFT) updated SQL Azure a good while back it broke everyone who did not have SP1 on their machines...

Comment: Do you know where I can download the other service packs?

Comment: It's been a while since I did it, I think this might have been it: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26727

Comment: This post might help too (look at the big flashing notes section): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/peterlau/archive/2012/02/28/get-started-with-sql-azure-resources.aspx

Comment: Can you try connecting from a different location e.g. 3G or home to rule out firewall issues like Brent mentioned? Possible to try connect from someone else machine to rule environment issues on your dev box?

Comment: I tried to connect from home and everything works perfectly.. so maybe something at work here is blocked, I tried to enable port 1433 and I added the inbound rule to my firewall..

Comment: Cool, sounds like its your LAN firewall (not your local VM), you would need to discuss with your security team about getting a firewall burn.

Answer (score 0):

Does the location you're connection from block outbound traffic/connections on port 1433? This is actually a bit more common than folks realize. If you're 100% positive its not blocked, two things I'd recommend trying are a) remove and readd the rule b) put in a more specific rule using the IP you're actually coming from.

Comment: Is that a local firewall rule (on your dev box) or one at your locations firewall if you are in an enterprise?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the username is correct. You can also try to use the following format:

```
<login>@<server>
```

In addition, I would like to suggest you to check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336282.aspx for some general troubleshooting guidelines about connecting to SQL Azure.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.