# 'Server Explorer' > 'Windows Azure' > 'SQL Databases' in VS2013 does not show any databases

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-sql-database

According to: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2013/10/23/windows-azure-sdk-2-2-release.aspx

> The SQL Database node is a welcomed addition to the Windows Azure
>   Server Explorer. Now you can browse your SQL Azure databases without
>   knowing the virtual machine or connection string to the database. We
>   automatically configure the firewall so that you can access the
>   database from your developer workstation. You can also open your SQL
>   Azure database in SQL Object Explorer for a complete database
>   management experience.

[image: SQL Databases from Windows Azure shown in Server Explorer]

However, I have added a SQL Database in my Windows Azure Management Portal but it does not appear in Server Explorer, the SQL Databases branch is completely empty. I also have a Web Site which *does* show up in Server Explorer.

Any ideas what the problem is?

I've tried refreshing and restarting Visual Studio, and signing out and back in again.

I thought it might be this [Can't connect to Windows Azure Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227186/cant-connect-to-windows-azure-database) (even though the MSDN documentation says the firewall is automatically configured). However I can connect with SQL Server Management Studio over port 1433 fine.

I can of course open SQL Server Object Explorer and do Add SQL Server and add the connection string in there, and browse the tables etc in the same way, but I was just under the impression they should appear automatically under Windows Azure.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and actually, I'm not sure how it would even work since you need the SQL Server administrator credentials to connect to Azure SQL Server databases.  I see no place to provide anything other than the Azure account credentials.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

SQL Databases do not yet support the OAuth signon in Visual Studio and they still require a management certificate to interact with them in VS.  If you right-click the Windows Azure node in the server explorer tree and select Manage Subscriptions you can then switch to the Certificates tab and import a management certificate.

Comment: This worked great. I used this link to make the cert, and exported it from certmgr.msc to upload it to Azure in the Settings section. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg551722.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure if this has changed since this answer was provided however all you need to do now is Right Click on Windows Azure and go to manage subscriptions,click on certificates tab then import and download subscriptions file, once the file is downloaded simply point the dialog box to it and all should be ok

Comment: Yakyb, what you described is the exact same thing described in the Answer itself :)

Answer (score 3):

After right-clicking on Windows Azure, click on the Certificates Tab. There will be a link that says something like download certificate - sorry I can’t remember the exact wording. After clicking on this link, a browser should open up allowing you to download and save the certificate. Then go back to VS and import that certificate.